# Remove outliers in data, keep the original trend

Tags: python, data-cleaning, curve-fitting, outliers

[image]

In my plot, there are just several noises as you can see. I tried to use scipy.signal savgol_filter, but the trend has changed. I just wanna remove these noises and make them fit the curve. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

i think you are confusing noise with outliers, please refer to: [the-basic-difference-between-noise-and-outliers](https://medium.com/@aatl2012/the-basic-difference-between-noise-and-outliers-in-data-cd3ff32343e0).
You may try to remove outliers on many different approaches, e.g. using z-score:

```
df = df.mask(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 2) # here we are setting limit on z-score on 2 - you can experiment with values best suited to your data
```

Important: you should perform it after removing trend from your data.

Answer (score 3):

Let's recreate a dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats, signal, optimize

np.random.seed(12345)

def model(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x) + c

x = np.linspace(0, 350, 200)
y = model(x, 100, 0.01, 75)
n = np.random.normal(size=x.size)
yn = y + n

yn[20] *= 0.75
yn[21] *= 0.5
yn[22] *= 1.75
yn[23] *= 0.25
yn[24] *= 0.20
yn[25] *= 0.75
yn[100] *= 0.5
yn[101] *= 1.75
```

If outliers are not too strong or too many, we can estimate trend by fitting the curve with outliers:

```
popt1, pcov1 = optimize.curve_fit(model, x, yn)
yhat1 = model(x, *popt1)

# (array([9.27557251e+01, 1.02647524e-02, 7.64660389e+01]),
#  array([[ 1.94284082e+01,  7.21272130e-04, -3.70396525e+00],
#         [ 7.21272130e-04,  1.80489353e-06,  3.75303063e-03],
#         [-3.70396525e+00,  3.75303063e-03,  1.05002199e+01]]))
```

Which is already close to optimal parameters but is dominated by outliers (see covariance).

Or we can smooth the curve with some filter as you suggested:

```
yhat1 = signal.savgol_filter(yn, 150, 3)
```

Then, as @Matmozaur suggested, the z-score is a good criterion to filter outliers:

```
zs = stats.zscore(yhat1 - yn)
mask = np.abs(zs) < 2.
```

Now we have identified outliers, we can fit function without them:

```
popt2, pcov2 = optimize.curve_fit(model, x[mask], yn[mask])
yhat2 = model(x, *popt2)

# (array([9.90714297e+01, 1.01604158e-02, 7.54550734e+01]),
# array([[ 5.81279449e-01,  1.70129801e-05, -1.13880755e-01],
#        [ 1.70129801e-05,  4.43252922e-08,  1.00312909e-04],
#        [-1.13880755e-01,  1.00312909e-04,  3.04817515e-01]]))
```

Which is a fairly acceptable fit for such setup.

[image]

As suggested by @mikuszefski, an alternative option is to estimate the trend using [`least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) and using a `loss` that penalizes the outliers such as `cauchy` loss.

```
def residuals(args, x, y):
    return model(x, *args) - y

result = optimize.least_squares(residuals, x0=(10, 0.1, 10), args=(x, yn), loss="cauchy")
popt1b = result.x
# array([1.00306426e+02, 1.00068743e-02, 7.49353910e+01])
```

Which returns a proper set of parameters without the need to remove outliers so it can be used directly or with the previous procedure for outliers removal.

[image]

This figure shows the impact of outliers on naive trend estimation with `curve_fit` while `least_squares` equipped with `cauchy` loss is not dominated by outliers.

Comment: little add-on: if the presence of the outliers affects `curve_fit` too much, you can use `scipy.optimize.least_squares` with an according `loss`

Comment: @mikuszefski, I have updated my answer with your suggestion. Cheers